# Possible Case When Use with Ranges (impossible?)

Tags: sql, case-when

Sorry, I'm new to this, so I'm not sure I'm formatting this all correctly. I have the following table:

---

```
DROP TABLE mytable; 

CREATE TABLE mytable
( employee_id INTEGER(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  vendor VARCHAR(1) , 
  lineofbiz VARCHAR(1), 
  state VARCHAR(2) , 
  company_name VARCHAR(8), 
  company_id INTEGER(1) 
); 

INSERT INTO mytable(employee_id,vendor,lineofbiz,state,company_name,company_id) 
VALUES (123,'A','D','CA','Peasants',1); 

INSERT INTO mytable(employee_id,vendor,lineofbiz,state,company_name,company_id) 
VALUES (123,'A','M','CA','Peasants',1); 

INSERT INTO mytable(employee_id,vendor,lineofbiz,state,company_name,company_id) 
VALUES (123,'B','V','CA','Peasants',1); 

INSERT INTO mytable(employee_id,vendor,lineofbiz,state,company_name,company_id) 
VALUES (234,'C','V','CA','Plebians',2); 

INSERT INTO mytable(employee_id,vendor,lineofbiz,state,company_name,company_id) 
VALUES (234,'C','M','CA','Plebians',2); 

INSERT INTO mytable(employee_id,vendor,lineofbiz,state,company_name,company_id) 
VALUES (234,'C','D','CA','Plebians',2); 

INSERT INTO mytable(employee_id,vendor,lineofbiz,state,company_name,company_id) 
VALUES (345,'C','M','CA','Plebians',2); 

INSERT INTO mytable(employee_id,vendor,lineofbiz,state,company_name,company_id) 
VALUES (345,'C','D','CA','Plebians',2); 

INSERT INTO mytable(employee_id,vendor,lineofbiz,state,company_name,company_id) 
VALUES (345,'C','V','CA','Plebians',2);
```

---

I feel as though I have a minor grasp, but I'm running into a wall.

1) In the above table, I want to insert a new column that has a flag where an employee_id is flagged as being in a large company or small company. I'll write my wrong query below, so maybe it'll help describe the issue.

---

```
select case when (count (distinct employee_id) > 1) 
            then as 'Large' else 'Small' from mytable;
```

---

I suppose I want to insert a new column with that validation, but I'm not sure how to do that.

If I'm breaking protocol, please let me know!

Comment: Given your sample data, what are the desired results?  Also, you might want to look into `normalization`, will help you out in the long run...

Comment: Oh, interesting. normalization is also quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to determine if a company is large or small, depending on the number of employees, I think this is the query you were attempting to write.

```
SELECT company_id, 
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT employee_id) > 1 THEN 'large' 
        ELSE 'small' 
    END as company_size
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY company_id;
```